# Netty with RestEasy and FileServer

Tags: java, netty, resteasy

I can use Netty with [Resteasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d0e2690) or as a [Fileserver](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServer.java):

```
public void file()
{
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
        new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
             Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new HttpStaticFileServerPipelineFactory());
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
}

public void rest()
{
    ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
    deployment.getActualResourceClasses().add(RestClass.class);

    NettyJaxrsServer netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();
    netty.setDeployment(deployment);
    netty.setPort(8080);
    netty.setRootResourcePath("");
    netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
    netty.start();
}
```

Both together are possible with different ports, but how can I integrate both approaches running one Netty server on a single port?

**Update**
Currently I use this setup:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-netty</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would basically have to combine the different handlers into a new `ServerPipelineFactory`. One approach would be to create a pipeline that has the common handlers already in place, plus a "dispatcher" handler that inspects the request and depending on the URL path dynamically adds handlers for static file serving or for resteasy processing.

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples for the described scenario?